# GO - How to convert public key from string to PEM format

Tags: go, jwt

I am trying to use jwt library to do jwt validation. And i am getting public key from another application by calling its REST endpoint which is returning public key in string format.

So now when trying to send that public key in same string format, i am getting "Invalid key format". Any help on how to convert string formatted key to a valid PEM format would be great.

```
func (test *TESTStrategy) doJWTValidation(token string, key string, logger *util.Logger) (TESTResponse, error) {
    parsedToken, jwtErr := jwt.Parse(token, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return decodedJWT.ParsedPubKey, nil
    })
```

Below is the error what i am getting when passing key as a string to jwt.Pasrse() call.

[image]

Public Key:
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsFWkb/eSl6I3DRVhaonW3DFy8EnL0yaPiDzCcOLuYfBjN9zZIR1wXmnMJFle1K89qHGg42wgweVTIwA1XFTfoUKSziwsjF6FscZX5H56ZYyS/wWiO3rWWynlfbSZt+ga71+ndsu+A0Dy7Nn7ZgP8kRsu4UM5vE7QQTRERNiUKpzScN1cgZUFUqSddQmkwTEN8hH1mFX1Mum54NGqWIlmQxQDrOyogmMXIaaakhabcmuIPMULVVDVwUJC9sSDsc/j05qcZn3kkiEBRyiYB6ZLY2W7WfiV+dB7/icPONsYSD0FxHWEGNnbqtiGoNf9WZWtaP+o8WMR9sB3GKGVnbLvbQIDAQAB

Comment: pem is a string format - can you be more specific what you're trying to convert from?

Comment: Thanks for response. I just updated ticket with more precise info. To your question, i am getting "key is of invalid type" when i am passing key as a string format.

Comment: Please paste the error as text rather than a screenshot as your error is truncated. Also, could you post a sample of the public key you are receiving as no-one can help if they don't know what format it is in. Since it's the public key, there shouldn't be any security concerns.

Comment: OK, but my question was what format are you trying to convert from?

Comment: From string to encoded pem. But before that, i am puzzled why string format is giving error as jwt.parse() takes key in a string format only. Anyway, my goal is to do jwt validation with given public key.

Comment: This is where it is failing. https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/24c63f56522a87ec5339cc3567883f1039378fdb/rsa.go#L60

Comment: As I noted, PEM is a string encoding, and "string" is not a specific encoding for a key. You need to know what format the key you're converting from is in order to convert it successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a PEM encoded key, it's just missing the BEGIN & END headers. The key is simple Base64 encoded, you can decode and unmarshal into a RSA key as follows:

```
base64Data := []byte(`MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsFWkb/eSl6I3DRVhaonW3DFy8EnL0yaPiDzCcOLuYfBjN9zZIR1wXmnMJFle1K89qHGg42wgweVTIwA1XFTfoUKSziwsjF6FscZX5H56ZYyS/wWiO3rWWynlfbSZt+ga71+ndsu+A0Dy7Nn7ZgP8kRsu4UM5vE7QQTRERNiUKpzScN1cgZUFUqSddQmkwTEN8hH1mFX1Mum54NGqWIlmQxQDrOyogmMXIaaakhabcmuIPMULVVDVwUJC9sSDsc/j05qcZn3kkiEBRyiYB6ZLY2W7WfiV+dB7/icPONsYSD0FxHWEGNnbqtiGoNf9WZWtaP+o8WMR9sB3GKGVnbLvbQIDAQAB`)
d := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(base64Data)))
n, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(d, base64Data)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
d = d[:n]
key,err:=x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(d)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
fmt.Println(key)
```

If you need the key in PEM encoded form, simple add the appropriate header and footer, e.g. `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` & `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`. Note that the BEGIN header must start on its own line and end in a new line (`"\n"`). The END header must also be proceeded by a new line.

Comment: Marking as solved. Thanks Martin, Just used jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM([]byte(key)) where "key" is added with header and footer as you suggested.